# Css not fading in smoothly after hover leave

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this image to fade back in smoothly after hover leave however it seems to just pop back in and I want the transition to look smooth and blend together on fade in the same way it works on fade out.

I may have gone overkill with the css but my main objective is to have the first div be an image and the second to be a background with information on it.

```css
.imageInfo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  color: black;
  font-style: italic !important;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.imageContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-width: 330px;
  height: 150px;
}

.cImage {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

imageContainer.img {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imageContainer img.play,
.imageContainer img.picture,
.imageContainer img.fade {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.imageContainer img.play {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.imageContainer:hover img.play {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.imageContainer div.picture {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, orange, red);
}

.imageContainer div.picture .fade {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.imageContainer:hover div.picture {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.imageContainer:hover div.picture .fade {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span class="imageContainer">
        <img  [src]="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"
          class="play cImage">   
            <div class="picture cImage gradient">
              <a class="fade">Baby Yoda</a>
              <div class="imageInfo fade">
               <strong>Date:</strong><span>"01/01/1999"</span>
</div>
</div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `src` instead of `[src]`. Change `<img [src]="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="play cImage" />` to `<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="play cImage" />`

```css
.imageInfo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  color: black;
  font-style: italic !important;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.imageContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-width: 330px;
  height: 150px;
}

.cImage {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

imageContainer.img {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imageContainer img.play,
.imageContainer img.picture,
.imageContainer img.fade {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.6s linear, visibility 0.6s linear;
}

.imageContainer img.play {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 0.6s linear, visibility 0.6s linear;
}

.imageContainer:hover img.play {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.6s linear, visibility 0.6s linear;
}

.imageContainer div.picture {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.6s linear, visibility 0.6s linear;
}

.gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, orange, red);
}

.imageContainer div.picture .fade {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.6s linear, visibility 0.6s linear;
}

.imageContainer:hover div.picture {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 0.6s linear, visibility 0.6s linear;
}

.imageContainer:hover div.picture .fade {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 0.6s linear, visibility 0.6s linear;
}
```

```html
<span class="imageContainer">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="play cImage">   
            <div class="picture cImage gradient">
              <a class="fade">Baby Yoda</a>
              <div class="imageInfo fade">
               <strong>Date:</strong><span>"01/01/1999"</span>
</div>
</div>
</span>
```

After your comments if I understand correctly then you want same transition effect `on mouse in` and `on mouse leave`. Then `transition-timing-function` will be `linear` instead of `easy-in-out | easy-in | ease-out` etc. You have to read more about [transition-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function). And you have to separate `transition-propery` like (`opacity`, `visibility`). You have to read more about [transition-property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property).

You wrote transition only for `:hover` or `mouse in`. Now you have to write transition for `mouse leave`. You `CSS` will be like this.

```
.imageContainer img.play{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: opacity 0.6s linear, visibility 0.6s linear;
}

.imageContainer:hover img.play{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.6s linear, visibility 0.6s linear;
}
```

Check above code snippet it's working `mouse in` and `mouse out`.

Comment: Ok  thanks for that but however the issue still remains when you hover away from the container If you notice that flash. I dont want that. I want it to fade the image back in once you leave from hover and it needs to blend so you can see the transition happening. Currently that transition only happens when fading the background image in

Comment: @CodeMan03 I edited my ans. Check if it solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a real way (that I know of, at least) to make it fade in simply when your mouse leaves but not when it loads. So, I just made it load in with the show animation and placed on a "loading..." that fades as the images comes on. Sorry, but I couldn't adapt it with you code, because I couldn't make complete sense of it, so I created my own code. Adapt it to fill your code:

```css
img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-name: show;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

img:hover{
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#hi{
  background-color: green;
}

#loading{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fade{
  from{opacity: 1;}
  to{opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes show{
  from{opacity: 0;}
  to{opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<p>Opacity Animation Test</p>
<div>
  <p id="loading">Loading...</p>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <div id="hi">
    <a href="#">HI</a>
    <p><b>Date:</b>1/1/10</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The vital parts are the z-index attributes (keeps the picture in front of the text), position absolute, the animations (for obvious reasons), animation-name and animation-duration (they trigger the animation, but feel free to edit the duration time), and the opacity.

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Ive added a snipped of what I mean. there should be an initial image in the container. When the user hovers then it should fade out and the background div should fade in. When they hover away then the background image fades out and the original image needs to fade in.

Comment: That already is happening. I added a background color to it too.